The handle is invalid exception while capturing screen using Graphics.CopyFromScreen() on the remote server via Task Scheduler
I have a C# stand-alone (EXE) application, that does some data processing. At the end of the process, program takes a screenshot, saves the image (PNG) to a local folder and exits.
When I run this program locally, it works fine. The data processing is accomplished successfully, the screenshot is taken and the image is saved in the same folder with this EXE file.
Same goes for when I run this app manually on a remote Windows server. It works great.
However, the problem occurs, when this program runs as a scheduled task on a server. I setup a Windows Task Schedule to execute this program daily at certain time. But for the debugging purpose, I disabled all of the data processing code, only leaving code that takes the screenshot. In other words, the program opens a Console Window, prints some text using Console.WriteLine("Hello World"), takes the screenshot and goes into Console.ReadLine() awaiting user's input and then exits entirely. I scheduled this program to run one minute after I close the remote server.
This is where the problem occurs. For example, it is 10:00 AM now. I scheduled this program to run at 10:01 AM and closed the server by hitting "x" button. When I come back a couple of minutes later, I see Console Window opened with "Hello World" text and it's waiting for my input. I press  key and program closes. But there is no screenshot image created.
Please see my code below:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

    string filename = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Screenshot.png");

    ScreenCapture(filename);

    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> key to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void ScreenCapture(string filename)
{
    Rectangle res = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    int screenLeft = res.Left;
    int screenTop = res.Top;
    int screenWidth = res.Width + 384;
    int screenHeight = res.Height + 216;

    try
    {
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
            }
            bitmap.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Source + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}

Thank you in advance. I appreciate any help!

Under which user is the scheduled task running? And which user's window station (desktop) do you want a screenshot of? Kind of weird to be taking screenshots on a server.

The reason for taking screenshots is to prove to client that process ran successfully and created necessary datasets based on client's input.  Client will receive an email with the attached screenshot.  It's all just corporate politics.  It just must be done this way.
In terms of the user, it's the network account dedicated to this server.  This account never logs out and server doesn't get rebooted unless it's a maintenance window.

Do you really have an empty catch block there? Very useful. Did you try to write to the Console the value of Application.StartupPath? Why are you using a WinForms property in a Console app?

No, of course not.  I'm not that dumb.  I always output exceptions in the try/catch block.  The error has to do with Graphics.CopyFromScreen method and it says Invalid Handle.

Here are the details of the exception:
System.Drawing The handle is invalid    at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)    at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)    at ScreenCapture.Program.ScreenCapture(String filename)

I guess my real question was why a process is running on a server with a UI, normally server processes would run without logging in, like IIS or other webservers etc. I understand that's just what you have, still weird. Either way, still not clear: is the scheduled task running as the same user as the process you want to capture?

"and closed the server by hitting "x" button" means you had no remote desktop session open for the user the task run under so at the time the screenshot should be taken there was no actual desktop?

Charlieface, thanks for your question.  The app is a console window that runs on a remote server processing some Oracle data received by client.  It doesn't have to be console app, it can be a C# service or even a webservice, but it is what it is right now.  It shouldn't matter what kind of app it is, as long as it does the job per client's requirements.

Ralf, thanks as well.  When "x" button is clicked, the session does not fully logout.  This server constantly running on a dedicated account.  The task for this app in a Task Scheduler is set to be run as this particular account.

The exception is referring to an invalid Handle. When you call CopyFromScreen() (which GetDc(nullptr) + BitBlt()), the handles are the Screen's hDC and the derived Graphics's hDC. Try first making main async and await Task.Delay(500) before calling your method. If it fails, call those functions directly: get the handle of the Desktop with GetDesktopWindow() and call GetDc() with that handle -- Move the text of the exception to the body of the question, and add back whatever code is in the catch block, otherwise some may think you are what you say you're not :)

Another thing to test is the state of Screen.PrimaryScreen. If you have only one monitor (i.e., there's no active multi monitor support), use SystemInformation.VirtualScreen instead of the Bounds property

Jimi, thank you for your suggestions.  I will give it a try and follow-up with the results.

Jimi, I changed my Main to use async/await method, but it did not work.  I'm going to VirtualScreen instead of Bounds property.  I'll send an update when done.

Jimi, changing to VirtualScreen did not fix the problem.

After doing some research, it seems like quite a few folks had experienced same exact problem.  It sounds like, when Remote Desktop is minimized or closed, the session becomes inactive and desktop becomes invisible to the application.  That's why it cannot take screenshots.
Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a resolution.
Any help would certainly be appreciated.
